# Drag and drop a div easly from one to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to move a div from a div to another one easily.

I have here the style and the html so you can help me, here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #myDIV {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: solid #000 2px;
        background-color: #d12;
      }

      .ZE {
        position: fixed;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color:  #73AD81;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 20px 60px;
        border: 2px solid #965D31;
      }

      .ZE.left {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }

      .ZE.right  {
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }

      .ZE.up {
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }

      .ZE.down {
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        bottom: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent-div">
      <div class="myDIV" id="myDIV"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var parent = document.getElementById("parent-div");

      // for demo purposes
      var data = {
        isConnected: true
      },
          classes = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'];

      //socket.on("isConnected", function(data) {
      // Receive the 'data' and check if 'isConnected' is true

      // loop for demo purposes
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        if (data.isConnected === true) {
          parent.innerHTML += "<div class='ZE " + classes[i] + "'></div>"
        }

      }
      //});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to move the `#myDIV`div into the other divs that i created. `ZE left` `ZE right` ... etc . i think that it is easy , but i'm new at this stuff so i need a little help.

Comment: Do you mean clone your `#myDIV` into the other newly created divs?

Comment: just drag and drop it over there

Comment: What about using plugin such as [jquery-ui droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/)?

Comment: and how can i do that ?

Comment: Read the docs there are examples there. If you have a specific question I will happy to help. Don't forget to nutify me by add my username to your comment, Like @MoshFeu,

Comment: You don't need jquery-ui. HTML5 has the whole functionality needed.

Comment: and how can i do that ,  i really need an answer because i searched  for a long time and i didn't find anything. @MoshFeu

Comment: Just a little question. How can you drop a larger element within a smaller one?

Answer (score 0):

This post is asking something similar. (I asked the question). If you look at the JSFiddle code that is in the comments section and the answer you should be able to pick up how to do this. It took me a couple of hours to customise it to my needs but I go there. So be patient and keep trying with that code. You will need to include the JQuery library reference in your  section like so

```
<head>
   <!--JQuery Lirary for adding answer steps-->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Hope that helps get yo on the right track